# JMeter doesn't record HTTP traffic on the mobile device

Tags: jmeter

I have to record HTTP traffic on my mobile phone with JMeter to do so I added `HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder` to `Test Plan` and set the port inside recorder to `8888`. I also added `Recording Controller` inside `Thread Group` then I clicked Start button inside HTTP Proxy Server to generate certificate, after that I used `ipconfig` in the cmd to get my computer's IP address.

On my mobile I install transferred JMeter certificate and modify Wi-Fi network by setting parameter `Proxy settings` to `Manual` and typing IP of the computer as a `hostname` and `8888` as `proxy port`.

According to the instructions on the Internet, this configuration should allow me to record traffic on the phone, but nothing like that happens. It seems to me that something may be wrong with the proxy settings, because after I manually configured proxy the phone is offline. Does anyone know what the cause could be and how to fix this problem?

`jmeter.log` file doesn't show any errors, only the following information.

```
2021-06-01 20:26:07,289 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :root_ca:
2021-06-01 20:26:07,289 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :intermediate_ca:
2021-06-01 20:26:07,290 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Creating Daemon Socket on port: 8888
2021-06-01 20:26:07,291 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Test Script Recorder up and running!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has been solved. It was because my home network was set to public, all I had to do was change this setting and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your "computer" and your "mobile" must "see" each other, i.e. to be on the same [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork)
2. Your "computer" need to allow inbound connections to port 8888 in its [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) rules
3. Depending on your "mobile" operating system you need to take extra steps in order to be able to record HTTPS traffic;

   - [in case of Android N or higher you need to configure your application network security accordingly](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html), see [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices) article for more details  [in case of Android 11 or higher you need to additionally trust](https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/android-11-trust-ca-certificates/) the certificate
   - in case of Apple you need to [enable full trust for root CAs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477)
4. In case of any problems inspect [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and your "mobile" logs, the reason should be listed in at least one of them

Comment: 1. Both computer and mobile are connected to the same Wi-Fi network.
2. I added the rule to allow connections to port 8888.
3. My mobile OS is Android 11. I install ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA as follows: settings>Security>Encryption & Credentials>Install from storage>CA Cetificate>Accept warning>Choose certificate>Confirm the installation
4.I haven't checked the jmeter.log file, maybe there will be a reason

Comment: I inspect jmeter.log file but unfortunately it doesn't say anything.